# Error while creating new Android project in Eclipse

Tags: android, dependencies

I'm very new in Android and trying to create my first "Hello world" application using Eclipse under Windows 7. But during the wizard I get an error and I don't know how to resolve it.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I came across this error while ago.

You need to remove whole SDK and download it again from developer website.

There was some solution which suggested only removing compatibility library but it didn't worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

try updating  your eclipse .
Go to help ->check for updates